# Why does my docker image fail when running as task in AWS ECS (Fargate)?

Tags: docker, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a docker image in ECR, which is used for my ECS task. The task spins up and runs for a couple of minutes. Then it shuts down, after reporting the following error:

```
2021-11-07 00:00:58npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-11-07 00:00:58npm ERR! /home/node/.npm/_logs/2021-11-07T00_00_58_665Z-debug.log
2021-11-07 00:00:58npm ERR! signal SIGTERM
2021-11-07 00:00:58npm ERR! command sh -c node bin/www
2021-11-07 00:00:58npm ERR! command failed
2021-11-07 00:00:58npm ERR! path /usr/src/app
2021-11-06 23:59:25> my-app@0.0.0 start
2021-11-06 23:59:25> node bin/www
```

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
LABEL maintainer="my-team"
LABEL description="App for AWS ECS"
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN chown -R node:node /usr/src/app
RUN apk add bash
RUN apk add openssl 
COPY --chown=node src/package*.json ./
USER node
ARG NODE_ENV=dev
ENV NODE_ENV ${NODE_ENV}
RUN npm ci
COPY --chown=node ./src/generate-cert.sh ./
RUN ./generate-cert.sh
COPY --chown=node src/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["npm","start"]
```

My package.json contains:

```
{
"name": "my-app",
"version": "0.0.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www",
  "test": "jest --coverage"
},
```

The app is provisioned using terraform, with the following task definition:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition" {
family                   = "dataviz_task"
network_mode             = "awsvpc"
requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
cpu                      = "256"
memory                   = "512"
task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.dataviz_ecs_role.arn
execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.dataviz_ecs_task_execution_role.arn

container_definitions = jsonencode([{
  entryPoint : [
    "npm",
    "start"
  ],
  environment : [
    { "name" : "ENV", "value" : local.container_environment }
  ]
  essential : true,
  image : "${var.account_id}${var.ecr_image_address}:latest",
  lifecycle : {
    ignore_changes : "image"
  }
  logConfiguration : {
    "logDriver" : "awslogs",
    "options" : {
      "awslogs-group" : var.log_stream_name,
      "awslogs-region" : var.region,
      "awslogs-stream-prefix" : "ecs"
    }
  },
  name : local.container_name,
  portMappings : [
    {
      "containerPort" : local.container_port,
      "hostPort" : local.host_port,
      "protocol" : "tcp"
    }
  ]
 }])
}
```

My application runs locally in docker, but not when using the same image in [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com) [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/).

To run locally, I uses a Make command `make restart`
which runs this from my Makefile:

```
build:
    @docker build \
        --build-arg NODE_ENV=local \
        --tag $(DEV_IMAGE_TAG) \
        . > /dev/null

.PHONY: package
package:
    @docker build \
        --tag $(PROD_IMAGE_TAG) \
        --build-arg NODE_ENV=production \
        . > /dev/null

.PHONY: start
start: build
    @docker run \
        --rm \
        --publish 8080:8080 \
        --name $(IMAGE_NAME) \
        --detach \
        --env ENV=local \
        $(DEV_IMAGE_TAG) > /dev/null

.PHONY: stop
stop:
    @docker stop $(IMAGE_NAME) > /dev/null

.PHONY: restart
restart:
ifeq ($(shell (docker ps | grep $(IMAGE_NAME))),)
    @make start > /dev/null
else
    @make stop > /dev/null
    @make start > /dev/null
endif
```

Why does my docker image fail when running as task in AWS ECS (Fargate)?

Comment: Can you output `/home/node/.npm/_logs/2021-11-07T00_00_58_665Z-debug.log`

Comment: Can you also paste the (docker run?) command you use to launch the container locally?

Comment: @mreferre question updated with how I run the container locally